# How do I print the assigned value of this letter instead of ascii number?

Tags: arrays, c, variables, printing

I want to print the assigned value of H = 2 by accessing the array. But when I access it from the array it gives me 72.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int H = 2;
  char a[20] = "Hello";
  printf("%d",a[0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Is the idea that since `a[0]` is the character `'H'`, you want your program to find a variable named `H` and print it out?  You can't do that in C; variable names are only seen by the compiler and you can't access variables by their names at runtime.

Comment: If you really need it, you have to make a big table with all the variable names as strings and pointers to the corresponding variables, and write code to search it at runtime.  But more likely, there is a better solution to whatever your real goal is.

Comment: "I want to print the assigned value of H = 2" --> `printf("H = %d\n", H);`

Answer (score 0):

assigning H=2 doesn't change its ascii value for you.

```
int H = 2;
```

H in the above statement is a variable.

```
char a[20] = "Hello";
```

While H in this one is a simple character in a string. Totally unrelated.

Comment: I am not relating them. I just want to print out the H=2 by accessing the array.

Comment: then, um, create an integer array and store it there

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own print function that will print the way you need.
And you can create a LUT (look up table) that will store values that you want to print. Like this (not sure about syntax, just show the idea):

```
int ASCII_RANGE = 256;
int LUT[ASCII_RANGE];
int i = 0;
int H = 'H';

for (i = 0; i < ASCII_RANGE; ++i)
{
    LUT[i] = i;
}
// here you define values that you want to print.
LUT[H] = 2;
```

And your printer:

```
void printer(int value)
{
    printf("%d", LUT[value]);
}
```

The same way your printer can receive string and in loop to print all characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t reassign character values.  What you can do is create an array that’s indexed by the character value:

```
int map[256];

for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) // initialize the map array
  map[i] = i;                   // so characters map to their
                                // default encoding
map['H'] = 2;                   // override the mapping for 'H'

char a[] = "Hello";
printf( "%d", map[a[0]] );    // print the value of map['H']
```